# Restarting celery workers not updating beat schedule

Tags: python-3.x, celery

I am attempting to restart the beat workers after issuing a POST command to my app to change the beat schedule. When I stop and restart the workers, they are not picking up the changes made to the celerybeat-schedule.db file. Isn't the beat schedule suppose to refresh when stopping and starting the workers? In the log I see beat stops and starts again. Below are the 3 functions I am calling with the POST commands, first I stop the workers, then I modify the schedule, then I restart the workers. Using django is not an option because I am already using flask.

```
def scheduler(frequency):
    celery_app.conf.CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
                                           'every-10-seconds': {
                                                                'task': 'tasks.add',
                                                                'schedule': int(frequency),
                                                                'args': (5, 5)
                                                                },
                                           }

def stop():
    subprocess.check_call(['celery', 'multi', 'stopwait', '1', '--pidfile=worker.pid'])
    return
def restart():
    subprocess.check_call(['celery', 'multi', 'start', '1', '-A', 'tasks', '-l', 'info',
                           '--pidfile=worker.pid', '--beat'])
    return
```

Comment: Depending on your install configuration, celerybeat and celery are two different processes. Try restarting celerybeat and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: What is the proper way to stop beat? I see how to start it.

Comment: What is the command to start it? I want to make sure I give you an answer that's helpful, and not one assumed by my particular installation.

Comment: Currently I am using this command to start everything:
celery multi start 1 -A tasks -l info --pidfile=worker.pid --beat

Comment: And then using the stop and restart function I posted above to stop and restart the beat workers

Comment: The only thing I can think of is restarting it doesn't maintain the change to the schedule. Have you verified that the schedule has the correct entry after the modification and restart?

Comment: Yep. I start the worker without a schedule entry, and then I schedule an entry, stop the workers, then restart them. Still doesn't pick up the new schedule, but the celerybeat-schedule.db file is updated when I view it.

Comment: Sorry to say it, then I'm as stumped as you are. Apologies I couldn't be of assistance.